# Understand the Proj construction and blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, blowup

I have some problem understanding the Proj construction. I hope I can understand it better by the following example:

> Let $I\subset R$ be an ideal, and consider  ${\rm Proj}(\oplus I^k)$, which is the blow-up of ${\rm Spec} R$ at $V(I)$. Can we see the closed points of ${\rm Proj}(\oplus I^k)$? For example, let $R=\mathbb C[x,y]$ and $I=(x,y)$. Then for any maximal ideal $J\subset R$ which does not contain $I$, there is a corresponding maximal ideal $\oplus I^kJ$ which corresponds to a closed point away from the exceptional divisor. Then, **what are the ideals corresponding to the closed points on the exceptional divisor**? I see the exceptional divisor corresponds to $\oplus I^{k+1}$, so these ideals should contain it.

I think a problem to me is, I don’t know how to see the geometry side of an homogeneous
ideal. For Spec, it is quite clear to me that the ideal $I \subset R$ can be interpreted
as the zero locus $V(I)\subset {\rm Spec} R$, i.e. the common zeros of $f\in I$, and maximal ideals corresponds to minimal closed subschemes, which are just closed points. What is the corresponding version in the Proj construction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To go from Spec to Proj: insert the word "graded" everywhere, and disallow anything containing the irrelevant ideal

Comment: Do you understand that Proj of a graded polynomial ring in $n+1$ variables is projective $n$-space? The projective $V(I)$ is again simply the zero locus, which is well-defined in projective space due to the homogeneity condition.

Comment: @math54321 Basically this is OK for me but I am confused about the closed point in the Proj. For example, let $I\subset R$ be a maximal ideal, then in ${\rm Proj }(R[t])$ the corresponding maximal ideal is $I[t]$, which is not “maximal” as it is contained in $I \oplus I t \oplus R t^2 \oplus R t^3 \oplus \cdots$. How should I think about this?

Comment: @TabesBridges Yes, but this is probably the only example I have in mind… I think my premier question is that I am confused about the the closed points in the Proj construction (see my comment above).

Comment: You seem to be mixing a few different questions together. For an $\mathbb{N}$-graded ring $R = \oplus_{i \ge 0} R_i$, the closed points of $\operatorname{Proj}(R)$ are exactly the graded ideals that are maximal with respect to not containing the irrelevant ideal $R_+ = \oplus_{i > 0} R_i$. In the case of blowups, the ring is $S =  R[It] = R \oplus It \oplus I^2t^2 \oplus \ldots$. Closed points of $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ are not the same as closed points of $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, nor of $\operatorname{Proj}(R[t])$

Comment: @math54321 No, I did not consider the blow-up. Here I just try to see the maximal ideals in ${\rm Proj}(R[t])$. I think the ideal I proposed is maximal (or am I wrong?) but it is certainly contained in another ideal which does not containing the irrelevant ideal.

Comment: OK, so if you're asking about $\operatorname{Proj}(R[t])$: by definition these are graded primes in $R[t]$ which don't contain $(t)$. These are in bijection with primes in $R$, via the correspondence you gave $P \mapsto P[t] = \oplus_{i \ge 0} Pt^i$, so closed points of $\operatorname{Proj}(R[t])$ are exactly the ideals which are maximal among this set (which are exactly $P[t]$ for $P \subseteq R$ maximal)

Comment: Note that your ideal $I \oplus It \oplus Rt^2 \oplus Rt^3 \oplus \ldots$ is not prime, since it contains $t^2$ but not $t$, so it doesn't give a point of $\operatorname{Proj}(R[t])$

Comment: @math54321 OK i think I make sense. So, in the homogenous setting, “maximal” is only in the sense of “maximal in (relevant) *prime* ideals”?

Comment: Yes exactly - they need not be (and generally are not) maximal ideals of the ring

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145240/discussion-between-user-x-and-math54321).

Comment: @UserX Did you manage to understand (in some satisfying level) the Proj construction and blow ups ?